# GWT ListBox unselected by default

Tags: java, gwt, selection, default

I've a GWT's ListBox with items:

```
listBox = new ListBox();
listBox.addItem("A");
listBox.addItem("B");
listBox.addItem("C");
```

and I would like it to be initialy unselected - so that no item is picked. The initial lack of selection should be symbolized by empty text and after selecting any item the user can't pick the "no selection item".

Unfortunately the following line:

```
listBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
```

throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Is it possible to obtain such behaviour with GWT ListBox?

Comment: then you could be having an empty string as first item initially, once user selected anything you can delete the first one.

Comment: Then, if the user would open the list for the first time, he/she will see the empty option and will be able to pick it.

Comment: you can validate it or listen to click event and delete the blank item.

Comment: I can't have the blank option. If delete on click, the the first non-empty option will be selected - it shouldn't work like this.

Comment: Thank you Reddy for the hints.

Comment: you can disable the first option on change or click event....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it's normal situation because when you call `setSelectedIndex()` it will check the index whether is in the range. There is method in ListBox class.

```
 private void checkIndex(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= getItemCount()) {
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
  }
```

So by default 0 index  will be selected. If you want to add an empty text item for the first item, add an additional item for zero-index with an empty string:

```
listBox = new ListBox();
listBox.addItem(" ");
listBox.addItem("A");
listBox.addItem("B");
listBox.addItem("C");
listBox.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
        public void onChange(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
            SelectElement selectElement = listBox.getElement().cast();
            selectElement.getOptions().getItem(0).setDisabled(true);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that if the user picks the blank item that it would then change to whatever the first non-blank item is?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that a ListBox uses a select tag.  With a select tag that doesn't specify the multiple attribute, the first item is selected by default by the browser, which you can't do anything to prevent.   You can modify this behavior, though - an option tag in HTML can have a selected attribute, which means that it is the default selection.  But GWT doesn't seem to provide any way to set an item as default-selected (it would be nice if there were an overload of addItem that took a boolean for default-selected, or a setDefaultSelected(int index) method).

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to "unselect" all values from a multiple GWT ListBox, you can always iterate over current selected items and set their "selected" value as false.

Here you can see how to create getSelectedItems() and unselectValues method.

```
public LinkedList < Integer > getSelectedItems() {
  LinkedList < Integer > selectedItems = new LinkedList < >();
  for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
    if (isItemSelected(i)) {
      selectedItems.add(i);
    }
  }
  return selectedItems;
}

public void unselectValues() {
  for (Integer index: getSelectedItems()) {
    setItemSelected(index, false);
  }
}
```